# Encrypt information on Java and Decrypt it on Objective-C/C++/C

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, encryption, blowfish

I'm trying to encrypt a string on Java and send it to an iOS device, so far I'm able to encrypt easily the string using [this functions](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/07/15/encrypt-and-decrypt-using-blowfish-in-java/) but the hard part is on iOS.

On iOS I've been experimenting with different Blowfish libraries from http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html but without success, the algorithms might not even be compatible with the Java output but I'm not sure so I'd like to ask for advice on decrypting this string on the device.

Comment: I assume the use of Blowfish is non-negotiable.

Comment: it is if you advise me about what algorithm to switch to :)

Comment: I would recc AES128 or AES256, both of which are handily supported in both java and iOS. Spend a little time surfing. Google `iOS AES Encryption"

Answer (score 0):

Use `AES256` or `AES512`. Put an eye on `salt` and `seed`. Or your encrypted string may not be readable after decrypting on other machine.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, use AES instead of Blowfish.  Even Schneier says not to use Blowfish - if you require extra security then use Serpent, otherwise use the standard.

In addition to using AES, I also recommend that you use [Counter Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) - this encryption mode doesn't require padding, so that's one less thing you need to worry about when matching up your encryption and decryption methods.  However, you're fine with using any of the other NIST modes other than Electronic Codebook.